# RealmObjectChangeListener is triggered even if managed object does not have any changes

Tags: java, android, realm

I get instance in Application class and  manage it in my baseActivity class as a global instance.

I have a save button on that gets strings from edittexts, set strings to the object and `insertOrUpdate()` to realm database.

Even there is no any changes on the object, listener is triggered and changeSet object returns as all fields are modified.

Probably i miss a point about Realm's basics.

My Realm version is 3.7.0.

Thank you for help.

My object;

```
    public class Ayarlar extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey private Integer Id;

        private String IcIp;
        private String DisIp;
        private String IcPort;
        private String DisPort;
        private String Sayfa;

// Getters and Setters 

    }
```

My Application class;

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    public static Realm baseRealm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    }
}
```

My BaseActivity class;

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (baseRealm.isClosed())
        {
            Realm.init(this);
            baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (baseRealm.isClosed())
        {
            Realm.init(this);
            baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        baseRealm.close();
    }
}
```

Object that i create from database and add on listener in a sub activity;

```
Ayarlar ayarlar = baseRealm.where(Ayarlar.class).equalTo("Id",0).findFirst();
        RealmObjectChangeListener<Ayarlar> listener = new RealmObjectChangeListener<Ayarlar>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Ayarlar ayarlar, @javax.annotation.Nullable ObjectChangeSet changeSet) {
                Log.d("chhh", "onChange: "+changeSet.getChangedFields()[0]);
            }
        };
        ayarlar.addChangeListener(listener);
```

Two blocks below are about override methods in my MVP classes,

Setting the fields with strings inside my MVP view class with a new Ayarlar object with the same id (id=0) also when i set the id other than '0' listener is not triggered as expected;

```
btn_kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPresenter.saveAyarlar(new Ayarlar(
                        0,
                        txt_icIp.getText().toString(),
                        txt_disIp.getText().toString(),
                        txt_icPort.getText().toString(),
                        txt_disPort.getText().toString(),
                        txt_Sayfa.getText().toString()));



            }
        });
```

and finally this is method that i commit the data inside my MVP presenter class;

```
 @Override
    public void saveAyarlar(Ayarlar ayarlar) {


        baseRealm.beginTransaction();

        baseRealm.insertOrUpdate(ayarlar);
        baseRealm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: What is your Realm version?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

`insertOrUpdate()` copies all fields from the provided object into the associated new/existing RealmObject, therefore it qualifies as modifying every field.

If you don't want to modify every field, then you should check against equality and set the field value only if it's different.

There is a discussion on this in https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2787 but it'll be a while before it happens if it does.

Comment: than there is no point to use a change listener if I check if field's changed with if-else logic for all fields.